# Fail to install Ubuntu 18.04 from USB to a brand new Acer Swift 1

Tags: system-installation, 18.04, acer

I've been trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 from USB to a Brand new Acer Swift 1 sf114-32-p8gg, No Matter what I do, it fails with the Same Error(s), as shown in the picture.

Already tried USB creator and Multiboot from Ubuntu, as Well as Rufus from Windows (Image written in both modes) - so far Everything failed.

Dl'ed the official Ubuntu 18.04 Image twice and checked the USB Drive for Errors, both are fine.

BIOS settings Options are sparse, disabled secure boot and Made Boot from USB the First priority.

Windows 10 is works flawlessly, but its a really annoying. I bought the machine to run it with Ubuntu (also open to flavors).
Already disabled hibernation Mode, so Windows shirts down completely.

Can anyone Help? Ideas? Suggestions?
It would be so nice to get Ubuntu installed in this fine ans affordable Laptop.

I already googled the Last Line of the Error

> Unable to find live File system

and endlessly tried to solve it.
Think its some small issue I am Missing, as Ubuntu should run just fine on Acer Swift 1s.

Always stuck on following errors after which the system has to be shut down:

//

```
[ 0.050004] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 4: a60000000002048
[ 0.050016] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ADDR fef4c9e0
[ 0.050027] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:706a1 TIME 1529146879 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 32
[ 16.305024] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
[ 16.305053] MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list
[ 16.306143] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
[ 16.307221] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
[ 22.112474] usb1-6: device descriptor Reader/64 error -110
[ 37.728481] usb1-6: device descriptor Reader/64 error -110
[ 38.092477] usb1-6: device descriptor Reader/64 error -71
[ 38.328479] usb1-6: device descriptor Reader/64 error -71
[ 39.504245] usb1-6: device not accepting address 5, error -71
[ 40.048242] usb1-6: device not accepting address 6, error -71
[ 40.048410] usb usb1-port6: unable to enumerate usb device

BusyBox v1.27.2 (ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands

(Initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system
```

//

I tried to install from USB 2 & USB 3 Ports, to no avail.

Thanks so much in advance for some answer, I'm really Desperate by now.

Comment: when you boot from USB have you seen all the 4 options? 1. Try ubuntu 2. Install Ubuntu.. Etc?

Comment: A Bios update might help, if available.

Comment: After BIOS/UEFI update,  you have to reset the changes you made in UEFI. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2370998 And all Acer require you to set UEFI password and then enable "trust" on the Ubuntu/grub .efi boot files from within UEFI.

Comment: @pratap yes all 4 Options were displayed
after BIOS Update Ubuntu works Like a Charm, thank you so much! Was reluctant to use the preinstalled win10 at all thats why i didn't think of it ;-) so question is solved thanks to your input

Answer (score 2):

This looks like some thermal issue with an overheating cpu core
But, **Intel** community forum shows that those issues are often caused by faulty **bios microcode**
And be solved by **upgrading or downgrading the bios firmware**...
That is what you should try first.

Comment: After the BIOS Update Ubuntu works Like a Charm! Thanks so much, would have never thought about Something so simple. Was reluctant to use the preinstalled win10 at all thats why i didn't think of it ;-)

Comment: Good to know! Please vote up and mark as solved :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but Andrei's link on running Ubuntu from USB drive was helpfull. Here's the steps for installing Ubuntu from USB to Acer Swift 1 or for that matter any laptop with flash storage, instead of just running Ubuntu from USB.

The following steps worked for me so hope it's some use for you too. Once you have a **Bootable Media of Ubuntu 18.04 USB**, insert it in your computer and boot from it.

1. Once you see the GRUB menu, select *Install Ubuntu*.
2. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installer should start. Choose your language and click on *Continue*.
3. Select your keyboard layout and once you’re done, click on *Continue*.
4. Mark the '**Minimal installation**' checkbox. Then click on *Continue*. Don’t mark *Install third-party software for graphics and Wi-Fi hardware, MP3 and other media*. Atleast I didn't and it worked for me, you get to isntall them later anyways.
5. Now click on *Yes* to unmount all the mounted partitions.
6. Now mark on '**Something else**' and then click on *Continue*.
7. Now the "tricky" part if you don't know what you are doing. You have to make some partitions. **Your hard drive** - which is probably listed as **/dev/sda** - should be selected at the bottom of the window as '*Device for boot loader installation*'.
8. Now you have to free some disk space in your hard drive. If you want, you can delete all the partitions. You can click on – button to delete a selected partitions.
9. We will need two partitions. A EFI System Partition and a Root partition. Now we will create /dev/sdc2 **EFI System Partition** of 512MB and /dev/sdc3 **EXT4 Journaling File System partition**. Give it at least 20GB of space. You can click on the + button to create new partitions. For both partitions the *Type for the new partition* should be '**Primary**' and *Location for the new partition* should be '**Begging of this space**'. For EXT4 set as *Mounting point* "**/**".
10. Once you’re done, click on *Continue*.
11. Click on *Continue* to write the changes to the disk.
12. Now select your time zone and click on *Continue*.
13. Now fill in your details and click on *Continue*.
14. The installation should start and in a few moments finish with out any hiccup.

Answer (score 0):

The Acer Swift 1 has a flash storage not a SSD or HDD. That means that you have to create 2 partitions: A EFI System Partition and a Root partition. You may need to change a few setting from bios, to access the EFI partition you created.
Try to follow the steps from this tutorial https://linuxhint.com/run-ubuntu-18-04-from-usb-stick/

Comment: Is my answer good enough now?

Comment: My Acer Swift 1 sf-114 32 has a 256 GB SSD (Micron), NOT MMC