# ubuntu 18.04 install not recognize partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have an Acer Swift sf315-52 with Windows 10 on it. I shrank the single partition to give space for Ubuntu. I boot the Acer using a Live Ubuntu install. If I boot up into test it out, gparted does see all the partitions Windows sees. Start install from testing and when it gets to where to install it, it only shows /dev/sda. No partiton table. Turned off secure boot in bios and all kinds of things.

Tried to add my gparted but it wouldn't let me embed it and can't link to a temp Live boot!

Comment: Lets see what gparted sees!

Comment: See also: Acer Swift 3
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2370998 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047065/fail-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-from-usb-to-a-brand-new-acer-swift-1 & Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I should have done this a while ago. Unfortunately I do not recall the exact question/answer I got my answer from but, in general, they were correct in saying the GPT was not correct coming from the manufacturer. Just used gparted to fix it. Then the install went smoothly and am happily dual-booting Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10, albeit I may forget I have Windows on it. :}