# Installing Ubuntu on Acer laptop

Tags: system-installation, acer

I recently installed Ubuntu on my PC and everything went perfect. Now I am trying to install Ubuntu on my Laptop Acer, but I have difficulties. I downloaded the Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS version and created a bootable usb flash drive with Rufus. Then I enabled the Boot option in the BIOS of the laptop, everything perfect, but when I insert the USB and select it from the BIOS to boot it, the following happens:

1. I get a black screen with options and I select the second one - Install Ubuntu.
2. Then I get an error message telling me:

```
error: /casper/vmlinuz has invalid signature.

error: you need to load the kernel first
```

3. I go in the command line and tried all possible commands that I found in similar posts...nothing helped. Another strange thing is that I dont get anything if I enter ls as a command:

```
grub> ls
```

This does not return anything.

4. I tried also to set a supervisor password in the BIOS etc, but nothing helped.

Someone has any ideas how can I get rid of Windows and install the Ubuntu?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Supervisor password & UEFI  "trust" setting are required after install. Sound like a Secure Boot issue. Is that on? I might try with secure boot off. What model Acer. Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Comment: It is an Acer Swift 1. Secure Boot is on. When I followed now the steps from the post, I got into the Security menu in the BIOS and selected UEFI file as trusted, HDD0 and EFI there is no ubuntu folder as described in the instructions from the post.

Comment: I disabled secure boot and it worked!

Comment: Another Swift: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047065/fail-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-from-usb-to-a-brand-new-acer-swift-1  Also mentions that UEFI update helps a lot.

Comment: Perfect, his issues has been solved this way. Is there a way to do this from the ubuntu test mode or I have to download them from another device and upload them on a USB. Sorry, I am not very familiar how to update the UEFI.

Comment: A few systems can be updated directly with LInux. https://fwupd.org/lvfs/devicelist
 & https://fwupd.org/vendorlist Most of us can download to a FAT32 formatted partition or external drive. I use my ESP which is FAT32 (but changed to allow writing into it). Then from inside UEFI open that file. Varies a lot by vendor, see what instructions they have. Some offer DOS bootable flash drive image also. A few seem to only update from Windows.

Comment: Thank you very much for the replies guys, I think this is getting too complicated so I will search for a specialist who can install the Ubuntu on my laptop. Thank you anyway for the great support! I really did things I have never imagined I will do :D