# Installing Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS on Acer, GRUB 2 package is hanging

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, mount, xubuntu

Since yesterday I try to install Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS on my Laptop Acer Swift 1 where I had Windows 10 previously. 
Initially I had some problems with the installation start, but I disabled "secure boot" and it worked. however, now the Ubuntu starts installing and everything goes smooth, but then the installation suddenly stops the progress and I get "Installing the grub2 package". This can last hours without any progress.

I tried to open the Terminal in the background and typed the commands:

```
sudo fdisk -l
sudo mount /dev/sdxY /mnt  (where x is altter and Y a number you have found in the previous step)
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sdx 
sudo update-grub
```

Well, this did not work. An error message occurred: "grub-install error: will not proceed with blocklists".

I have swap area, ext4 space and EFI space. Separating my free space into these categories did not help too. How can I finally install the Ubuntu?

Now if I start my laptop without the USB inside, I get a black screen with the title "GNU GRUB version 2.02" and I have to enter some commands.
What should be done? I get almost to the final stage, but the grub2 packages can not be installed.

Comment: The problem is that I dont have the Windows anymore. When I start the laptop now, I get a black screen with the title "GNU GRUB version 2.02" and I have to enter some commands.
Should I open the terminal from the BIOS?

Comment: oh, then that's fine, do this (you have to use option "try ubuntu" when the usb key boots to be able to open a terminal): https://askubuntu.com/a/182863/307184 you probably won't even need to install ubuntu after that. it should have both windows and ubuntu booting correctly after that.

Comment: Nice I followed the instructions there and I clicked on recommended boot repair, but now I am waiting for about 15 minutes and semms the boot repair has also issues. It says: "Reinstall GRUB. This may require several minutes" and it is loading. I am a patient person and will wait more, but I think something is wrong there :D

Comment: yeah it's really fast normally, takes about 1-2 minutes for me. something's wrong. maybe you'll have to use a windows install usb/CD to repair boot.

Comment: Other Swift installs: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162008/installing-ubuntu-on-acer-laptop?noredirect=1#comment1936345_1162008 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047065/fail-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-from-usb-to-a-brand-new-acer-swift-1